# how do I swap adjacent nodes in a linked-list with recursion?

Tags: recursion, linked-list

I have a solution to the following Leetocde question:
https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/

It is simply to swap adjacent nodes in a linked list.

```
def swapPairs(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:

    if not head or not head.next:
        return head

    # Nodes to be swapped
    first_node = head
    second_node = head.next

    # Swapping
    first_node.next  = self.swapPairs(second_node.next)
    second_node.next = first_node

    # Now the head is the second node
    return second_node
```

I am struggling to implement the recursion on an input, so say we have input Nodes N1,N2,N3,N4.

When we apply the recursive function I get:

```
N1 ->SwapPair(N3) ; with second_node = N2 
N3->None ; with second_node = N4
```

Then as we untangle it, I get:

```
N2-> N1-> N3 ->N4
```

The correct answer is of course `N2-> N1-> N4 ->N3`

I don't quite see how N1 is being connected to N4- any ideas?

Comment: Try to think about using a dummy node (point to head) to help.  And draw a diagram based on the logic..

Comment: The above is my attempt at the logic, but I can't see how it first together- esp N1->N4

Comment: Run your code and it's just fine and got correct result.  Not sure it's something missing here.

Comment: Daniel, I know it is correct, but I am struggling to understand parts of it as I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to visualise what happens with the example you gave. It is important to realise that each execution context of this recursive function, has its own set of local variables. Although the different execution contexts have the same names for their variables, they are distinct.

In the main call we have:

```
 head
  ↓
┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  
│ val: 1  │  │ val: 2  │  │ val: 3  │  │ val: 4  │
│ next: ───> │ next: ───> │ next: ───> │ next: ───> None
└─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘
  ↑            ↑ 
first_node    second_node
```

Then the recursive call happens, which has its own variables (with same names, but they are distinct):

```
                           head
                            ↓
┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  
│ val: 1  │  │ val: 2  │  │ val: 3  │  │ val: 4  │
│ next: ───> │ next: ───> │ next: ───> │ next: ───> None
└─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘
                            ↑            ↑ 
                           first_node   second_node
```

There is one deeper recursive call here, which again has its own `head` variable which is `None`

```
                                                    head
                                                     ↓
┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  
│ val: 1  │  │ val: 2  │  │ val: 3  │  │ val: 4  │
│ next: ───> │ next: ───> │ next: ───> │ next: ───> None
└─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘
```

... it returns `None` from the first `if` block.

The remaining recursive call gets back this `None` return value and assigns it to `first_node.next`:

```
                           head
                            ↓
┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐
│ val: 1  │  │ val: 2  │  │ val: 3  │  │ val: 4  │
│ next: ───> │ next: ───> │ next: ───┐ │ next: ───> None
└─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘│ └─────────┘   ^
                            ↑        └───────────────┘ 
                           first_node    ↑ 
                                        second_node
```

Then `second_node.next = first_node` is executed:

```
                           head    ┌──────────────┐
                            ↓      V              │ 
┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐│
│ val: 1  │  │ val: 2  │  │ val: 3  │  │ val: 4  ││
│ next: ───> │ next: ───> │ next: ───┐ │ next: ───┘   None
└─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘│ └─────────┘     ^
                            ↑        └─────────────────┘
                           first_node    ↑ 
                                        second_node
```

Let's reorder the visualisation of the last two nodes, without changing any references:

```
                                        head   
                                         ↓      
┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐
│ val: 1  │  │ val: 2  │  │ val: 4  │  │ val: 3  │
│ next: ───> │ next: ───┐ │ next: ───> │ next: ───> None
└─────────┘  └─────────┘│ └─────────┘  └─────────┘
                        │                ^
                        └────────────────┘
                            ↑            ↑                
                           second_node  first_node
```

Then `second_node` is returned out of the recursive call, and so we arrive back in the first execution context (with its own local variables), where `first_node.next` gets assigned that return value:

```
 head      ┌────────────────┐
  ↓        │                V
┌─────────┐│ ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐
│ val: 1  ││ │ val: 2  │  │ val: 4  │  │ val: 3  │
│ next: ───┘ │ next: ───┐ │ next: ───> │ next: ───> None
└─────────┘  └─────────┘│ └─────────┘  └─────────┘
                        │                ^
                        └────────────────┘
  ↑            ↑            ↑           
 first_node   second_node  returned
```

Then `second_node.next = first_node` is executed:

```
 head      ┌────────────────┐
  ↓        │                V
┌─────────┐│ ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐
│ val: 1  ││ │ val: 2  │  │ val: 4  │  │ val: 3  │
│ next: ───┘ │ next: ───┐ │ next: ───> │ next: ───> None
└─────────┘  └─────────┘│ └─────────┘  └─────────┘
       ^                │
       └────────────────┘
  ↑            ↑
 first_node   second_node
```

Let's reorder the visualisation again without changing references:

```
              head
               ↓
┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  
│ val: 2  │  │ val: 1  │  │ val: 4  │  │ val: 3  │
│ next: ───> │ next: ───> │ next: ───> │ next: ───> None
└─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘
  ↑            ↑
 second_node  first_node
```

Finally, `second_node` is returned as the new head.